# How to communicate with docker container in weave?

Tags: docker, weave

what I have done:

```
[spdocker@codebrag02 ~]$ weave launch
[spdocker@codebrag02 ~]$ weave env
export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/weave/weave.sock ORIG_DOCKER_HOST=
[spdocker@codebrag02 ~]$ eval $(weave env)

[spdocker@codebrag02 ~]$ weave run -idt --name hostA ubuntu bash
19c1caf5e6ebc6e398ddae58d253b3352847cdb78fdb58d77717450f3b156a0a
[spdocker@codebrag02 ~]$ weave run -idt --name hostB ubuntu bash
c0508959453c2d1af83ea98e7361be004fa75962897536bbb842a25382bae002
[spdocker@codebrag02 ~]$ docker exec -it 19c bash
root@hostA:/# ping hostB
PING hostB.weave.local (10.32.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from hostB.weave.local (10.32.0.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.096 ms
64 bytes from hostB.weave.local (10.32.0.3): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.061 ms
64 bytes from hostB.weave.local (10.32.0.3): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.075 ms
^C
--- hostB.weave.local ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.061/0.077/0.096/0.016 ms
root@hostA:/# [spdocker@codebrag02 ~]$ 
[spdocker@codebrag02 ~]$ ping hostA.weave.local
ping: unknown host hostA.weave.local
[spdocker@codebrag02 ~]$ ping hostB.weave.local
ping: unknown host hostB.weave.local
[spdocker@codebrag02 ~]$
```

I have start `weave service`, and start `2 docker container`, hostA and hostB. HostA ping succeed to hostB, but can I ping `hostA.weave.local` from the **DOCKER HOST** ?

Comment: What is the underlying system you are running on?  E.g. Ubuntu, CentOS, MacOS+Docker-toolbox

Comment: CentOS,I have tried to add weave dns to /etc/resolv.conf,it's worked,Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking for the container hostname to resolve from the outer host.  To make this happen, you need to change your host's DNS resolver to point at Weave's DNS resolver.  You can see its address with `weave dns-args` (this is formatted for use in `docker run`, but it's not too cryptic)

Exactly how to modify your host's DNS resolver depends on the OS of your host.

There are some other nuances that may be important; could you say a bit more about what you are trying to achieve at a higher level?

Comment: yes,I want the container hostname to resolve from the outer host.For example,I want the nginx server proxy pass to tomcat at port 8080,in nginx conf file I need host can communicate with docker container.